# Using Mongo Atlas API in Netlify Functions

Tags: mongodb, api, axios, netlify-function

I am trying to return a string from a mongo Atlas function that works locally, but whenever I run neltify deploy I get a message saying invalid URL. My .env variables, which are API URL and API key, are stored in my netlify server. I am new to mongo atlas API, so I am not sure what the issue is. My mongo function allows anonymous authentication as well as an API key. Here is my netlify function

```
import axios from "axios"
export async function handler(event, context) {
    const web = process.env.MONGO_ENDPOINT
    console.log(web)
    console.log("hi")
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(process.env.MONGO_ENDPOINT, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':'application/json', 
                'Access-Control-Request-Headers':' *',
                'api-key': process.env.KEY,
            }
        })
        const data = response.data

        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({ msg: data[0].quote })
        };
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err) // output to netlify function log
        return {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({ msg: err.message }) // Could be a custom message or object i.e. JSON.stringify(err)
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my mongo API endpoint

```
exports = function(arg){
  
    const mongodb = context.services.get("Cluster0");
    const db=mongodb.db("phi")
    const collection=db.collection("quotes");
    const item = collection.aggregate([{ $sample: { size: 1 } }])
    const quote =item
  return (quote);
};
```

As I said it all works locally, but not when I deploy to Netlify. Please let me know if you have any tips

I tried using the headers recommended by MongoDB and no success. I also tried to use the MongoClient package, but id rather use my mongo function endpoint

ANSWER: You do not need quotes around .env variables